# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wp_unique_post_slug()

Tags: php, wordpress

Recently i upgraded my classified website PHP version from 5.6 to 7.3

It works mostly fine, but when trying to add new listing i got this fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wp_unique_post_slug(), 1 passed in /home/admin/domains/houser.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/glocal/panel/post-edit.php on line 73 and exactly 5 expected in /home/admin/domains/houser.pl/public_html/wp-includes/post.php:4303 Stack trace: #0 /home/admin/domains/houser.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/glocal/panel/post-edit.php(73): wp_unique_post_slug('mieszkanie-ofer...') #1 /home/admin/domains/houser.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/glocal/panel/add-post.php(15): include('/home/admin/dom...') #2 /home/admin/domains/houser.pl/public_html/wp-content/themes/glocal/page-moje-konto.php(23): include('/home/admin/dom...') #3 /home/admin/domains/houser.pl/public_html/wp-includes/template-loader.php(98): include('/home/admin/dom...') #4 /home/admin/domains/houser.pl/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/home/admin/dom...') #5 /home/admin/domains/houser.pl/public_html/index.php(17): require('/home/admin/dom...') #6 {main} thrown in /home/admin/domains/houser.pl/public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 4303
```

In short, the problem is this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wp_unique_post_slug() (...) in /home/admin/domains/houser.pl/public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 4303
```

So i checked that error line and it outputs this:

```
function wp_unique_post_slug ($slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent ) {
    if ( in_array( $post_status, array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) || ( 'inherit' == $post_status && 'revision' == $post_type ) || 'user_request' === $post_type ) {
        return $slug;
    }
```

Any ideas why this error occur and how to fix it? I can't figure it out on my own. Thanks!

Comment: The first error explains it all.  On line 73 of post-edit.php only 1 argument is being passed to wp_unique_post_slug but 5 arguments are expected.

Comment: You either have to pass 5 arguments to the function when invoking in `post-edit.php`, or you set default values to the parameters in the function signature. And [here's](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php) why you get a fatal error now.